# Base64 encode characters in java, how to do in java

Tags: java-8, base64

I want to create this string on base of the current time.

For example:

`2014 06 04 16 21 20 79 ---> 14 06 04 16 21 20 79`

Then I can translate every two digits (except last two) for an alphanumeric character using table ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 - note that all of them are smaller than 59)

then

```
14 - O
06 - G
04 - E
16 - Q
21 - V
20 - U
```

---

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
String timeStamp = formatter.format(new java.util.Date());
String[] data = timeStamp.split(".", 5);

String abc = new String();
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    abc = abc.concat(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(data[j])));
}
```

Comment: can you show us any code that you've tried?

Comment: I'm not sure your description is clear. Are you trying to take a date/time (e.g. `2014/06/04 16:21:20.79`) and convert the numbers to Base64 characters (`OGEQVU`)? Also, please share your code

Comment: @Aziz yes exactly I want to generate strings based on date/time... I  am taking current time splitting into mm.dd.hr.min.sec .....want to get char (based on base64) for each value

Comment: `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString()`

Comment: You didn’t ask a question.